# MAMP - PHP - Class "Thread" not found

Tags: php, multithreading, mamp

on MAC I am running MAMP (PHP Version 8.0.8)

```html
class workerThread extends Thread {
    
    private $url;        
    
    public function __construct($url){
      ..
    }

    public function run(){
        ..
    }
}
```

I get the following error message:
**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Thread" not found**

How can I enable "thread" on MAC for MAMP?

What do I have to adjust in the following file?

> /Applications/MAMP/conf/php8.0.8/php.ini

or is it the following file, where I have to adjust?

> /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.0.8/conf/php.ini

Many Thanks,
Kalem

Comment: With phpinfo();  I know now which php.ini I may need to adjust.

Comment: There is no built-in class "Thread" in standard PHP, so presumably this code is intended for use with some library or extension - possibly "pthreads"? If so, that's what you need to install, so clarifying the question would give you your own answer.

Comment: @IMSoP Yes [there is](https://www.php.net/thread), and it is indeed part of the pthreads module, which is [no longer maintained](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/issues/929) and might not be compatible with PHP 8 (the developer's attention has shifted to the [parallel](https://www.php.net/parallel) extension instead, which does *not* offer a Thread class).

Comment: @rickdenhaan That is, as I said, part of a third-party extension, not part of standard PHP. The manual on php.net includes documentation for extensions hosted on "PECL", but they are all distributed separately from the core language, and that generally makes a difference to how they need to be installed.